# Pull data from PHP object received from twitter streaming api

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm using [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth-examples/blob/master/streaming.php) library to parse twitter stream in php.

It returned me variable `$data` with [***this object***](http://jsfiddle.net/MUdCb/)

object sample for stackoverflow

```
{
   "created_at":"Wed Jan 02 13:37:54 +0000 2013",
   "id":286466350610776064,
   "id_str":"286466350610776064",
   ...
}
```

looks like simple object, but how pull some data from this object?

`$data->created_at` doesn't work, it broke my head, why??

Comment: Not to ask the obvious, but isn't it because probably you don't understand that this is Json (http://json.org/) and you need to decode it first otherwise it's a string? http://php.net/json_decode ?

Comment: move this to answers, it's correct :)
thank you so much

Comment: Done that. However, take a little search next time ;) I could not find a good duplicate so far because it's such a general question, will link it later if I find one.

Comment: Also consider if you were missing an example with that library to add an example for that library, e.g. suggesting it in an issue: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth-examples/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isn't it because probably you don't see that this is a string containing [Json](http://json.org/) and you need to decode it first otherwise it's just a string variable and not an object?

See [`json_decode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));

object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["a"] => int(1)
    ["b"] => int(2)
    ["c"] => int(3)
    ["d"] => int(4)
    ["e"] => int(5)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is JSON response. Try [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)